# (Unity 2020.3.35f1) How does "Layout Priority" work?

Tags: unity-game-engine, layout

The manual mentions:

> "If a GameObject has more than one component with layout properties
> (for example, an Image component and a LayoutElement component), the
> layout system uses the property values from the component with the
> highest Layout Priority.
>
> If the components have the same Layout
> Priority, the layout system uses the highest value for each property,
> regardless of which component it comes from."

So does it not work to set the priority of the layout amongst other siblings in the hierarchy? My setup is something like this --

> Root object
>
> - Tab Names
> - Content

Tab Names has a "Preferred Height" 75px and "Flexible Width" is true.
Content has "Flexible Width" and "Flexible Height" set to true.
The Root object has "Vertical Layout Group" and "Child Force Expand" and "Control Child Size" for Width are both true. None for Height, because when I set either of those to true, the objects take up half of the parents height each (in my case the root object is 700 px in height).

1. Shouldn't the "Preferred Height" of the Tab Names keep it at 75? And (to counter this-)
2. Setting the priority, I thought it meant that the gameObject has more "weightage" in distribution of the space but it doesn't do anything! What is priority then?